# How to quickly change workspace in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, workspace

Anybody here have a advice how to quickly change workspace in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Until recently I was able to do `cmd` + ` on my mac but they seem to have removed it.

Answer (score 37):

Open Recent `workbench.action.openRecent` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: "workbench.action" property in settings.json is not available anymore in VS Code (I checked it in version 1.52). However pressing ctrl + R (even on mac) shows the recent files/folders panel which serves the purpose anyways.

Comment: In **Linux** this keyboard shortcut could be found most likely in `~/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json` (or in `Preferences: Open Default Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` option on **command palette**). Also, after the workspace picker window is open, you can keep pressing `Ctrl` + `R` and it will rotate and automatically change over workspaces (because of `workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNextInRecentFilesPicker` command set as default keyboard shortcut as well, at least in version [1.76.1](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_76))

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your key binding

```
    "command": "workbench.action.quickSwitchWindow",
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For people wondering, this only provides a quick way to switch between open windows of VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean extensionlist like "Php extension" to "Node Extension" i made a program which would be usefull for you [VS Code Workspace Changer](https://github.com/repiatx/VSWorkspaceChanger)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).